# How to stop jQuery $.animate when using increments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code to increment number using jQuery `$.animate`. I need to stop the animation whenever I need to, but calling `$("#el").stop()` does not work. Any ideas?

```
<script>
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  $({someValue: 40000}).animate({someValue: 45000}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(Math.round(this.someValue));
      }
  });
</script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

EDIT:

Please also provide a solution to stop the `$.animateNumbers` found on: https://github.com/talmand/jquery-animate-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation doesn't run on `#el`, so it cannot be stopped from there. It runs on the object you pass to `$()`, so you have to stop it there:

```
var obj =  $({someValue: 40000}).animate(...);
obj.stop();
```

Comment: I'm also using the plugin on https://github.com/talmand/jquery-animate-numbers. As you can see it doesn't return the `$.animate` object; it instead returns the object where you want to run the `$.text` function on. In that case how would I edit the plugin to make the `$.stop` work?

Comment: It works the same way. `animateNumbers` returns the jQuery object created by `$({...})`.

Comment: It seems to be returning the jQuery reference object where the you want to apply the number to: `$.fn.animateNumbers = function(stop, commas, duration, ease) { return this.each(function() { ... `. For example, `$("#el").animateNumbers()` returns the `$("#el")` object.

Comment: Exactly (that's what I meant). You always have to call `.stop` on the object you are animating.